# "Vazamento" de Session

Tags: php, session, mysqli

Ocorreu algo estranho enquanto estávamos homologando o sistema na REDE.

Bem, todas as vezes que um usuário faz o LOGIN no sistema, eu armazeno o ID dele da seguinte forma:

```
$_SESSION['usuario']['uid'] = $id_user;
```

e o direciono para o index.php

```
header('location:index.php'); die();
```

Alguma coisa aconteceu, uma única vez, que me deixou com receio.

O usuário CARLOS logou no sistema, e quando o JOÃO foi fazer o login, digitou user e senha e entrou como se fosse o CARLOS, e ainda mais estranho é que quando o USUARIO TAVAREZ digitou a o IP do sistema, nem na tela de login ele parou, ele foi redirecionado diretamente para o INDEX como CARLOS.

O que posso fazer para prevenir esse tipo de ocorrência?

Estou utilizando PHP/MySQLi

Conforme dito, abaixo código da Autenticação:

```
if(isset($_POST["signup"])){

  $user = filter_var($_POST['matricula']);
  $senha = md5(filter_var($_POST['password']));
  $captcha = strtoupper($_POST['captcha']);

  if(!isset($_SESSION['captcha'])){
    $_SESSION['captcha'] = 123456;
  }

  if($_SESSION['captcha'] <> $captcha){ // Captcha não bate
    $_SESSION['erro'] = 'captcha';
  }

  else{ // verificação do captcha OK        
    unset($_SESSION['captcha']); // limpo a sessão

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT s.id_servidor, s.matricula, s.senha, s.fnome, s.alias, s.celular1, s.email, s.nascimento,s.id_status, s.id_perfil, s.foto, s.extensao, l.ultimo_acesso, l.tentativas, l.block, d.id_setor_real FROM tbl_servidores s, tbl_login l, tbl_dados_profissionais d WHERE s.id_servidor = l.id_servidor and s.id_servidor = d.id_servidor and s.matricula = ?")){
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->store_result();

      if($stmt->num_rows == 1){ //Achei matricula no banco
        $stmt->bind_result($id_user, $matricula_user, $senha_user, $nome_user, $alias_user, $celular1_user, $email_user, $nascimento_user, $id_status_user, $id_perfil_user, $foto_user, $extensao_user, $ultimo_acesso_user, $tentativas, $block_user, $id_setor);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        if ($senha == $senha_user) {//senha OK

          if($block_user <> 's' and ($id_status_user == 1 or $id_status_user == 3) ){ // verifico se usuario não está bloqueado E status ativo.
            $_SESSION['usuario']['uid'] = $id_user; // gravo sessao

            if($ultimo_acesso_user =='0000-00-00 00:00:00'){//primeira vez
                $ultimo_acesso_user = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");  
            }

            $_SESSION['usuario']['ultimo_acesso'] = $ultimo_acesso_user;
            $_SESSION['tempolimite']=time()+$limite;

            if ($sqlupdate = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tbl_login SET ultimo_acesso = NOW(), registration_ip = '$ip', tentativas = 0, flag = 1 where id_servidor = '$id_user'")) {
            $sqlupdate->execute();
            $sqlupdate->close();
            }

            unset($_SESSION['contador']);
            unset($_SESSION['erro']);

            header('location:index.php'); die();// mando pro index
          }

          else{

            if($block_user == 's'){
             $_SESSION['erro'] = 'block';   
            }                       
            else{
             $_SESSION['erro'] = 'inativo';
            }
          }

       }//fim else senha == $senha_user

       else{ // errou a senha

         if($block_user == 'n'){
           $_SESSION['erro'] = 'erro_login';
           $qtde_tentativa = $tentativas + 1;

           if($qtde_tentativa == 10){
              $data = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
              $chave = $id_user.$data;
              $hash = md5($chave);

              $sqlupdate = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tbl_login SET tentativas = 10, registration_ip = '$ip', block = 's' , hash_desbloqueio = '$hash' where id_servidor = '$id_user'");
              $sqlupdate->execute();
              $sqlupdate->close();

              //envia sms e/ou email
              $variavel_msg = 'bloqueado';
              date_default_timezone_set('Brazil/East');
              $final1 = date('dmy');
              $final2 = date('His');
              $id_serv_rem = $id_user;
              $id = $id_serv_rem.$final1.$final2;

              include ("mensagens/email.php");
              include ("mensagens/sms.php");
              $_SESSION['erro'] = 'block';

            }

            else{

              $sqlupdate = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tbl_login SET tentativas = '$qtde_tentativa' where id_servidor = '$id_user'");
              $sqlupdate->execute();
              $sqlupdate->close();

            }

          }

          else{
            $_SESSION['erro'] = 'block';
          }

        }

      }

      else{

       $_SESSION['erro'] = 'erro_login';

       if(!isset($_SESSION['contador'])){
         $_SESSION['contador'] = 0;
       }

       $_SESSION['contador'] = $_SESSION['contador'] + 1;
       $qtde_tentativa = $_SESSION['contador'];

       if($_SESSION['contador'] >= 3){
          unset($_SESSION['contador']);
          header('location:block_1.php'); die();

       }

    }

}

else{

  $_SESSION['erro'] = 'erro_sql';
}
```

}

}

Comment: Como testaste isso? No mesmo *browser*?

Comment: Entao, 3 computadores diferentes.
CARLOS logou primeiro, JOÃO segundo, TAVAREZ  terceiro.
Importante saber q isso ocorreu uma única vez, e depois eu ainda não consegui reproduzir esse erro novamente.

Comment: Nunca me aconteceu tal coisa

Comment: Talvez o problema esteja no código de autenticação e não no código que manipula a sessão.

Comment: Renan, o código de autenticação é simples, com a seguinte lógica:
   
Recebo a Matricula a Senha e o Captcha

Se achei a matricula recupero a senha do banco e verifico se a Senha enviada é IGUAL

Se for igual eu gravo a sessão e direciono para o index

Senão, msg de erro

Comment: Concordo com o @Renan, se possível coloque o código da Auth.

Comment: @theteo `Se achei a matrícula recupero a senha do banco` com todo o respeito, já vi essa roda ser reinventada várias vezes. É provável que seu código de autenticação esteja perfeito, mas já vi várias vezes a estratégia desse tipo de consulta estar errado em todo tipo de sistema. Fica a sugestão de rever essa parte do código pois é um ponto que pode falhar.

Comment: não sei se seria a melhor solução, mais tente verificar o ip e o user agent. assim se cada usuário acessa o sistema de computadores diferente, terá ip diferente, forçando o usuário fazer o login.

Comment: vou editar o post com o codigo da Auth

Comment: Esse código cheio de pedaços faltando não vai ajudar muita coisa. Seria legal por o código na íntegra (menos senhas, claro) e de preferência formatar direito. Olhando assim já dá pra perceber que a lógica está meio confusa, mas com o código completo pode ser mais fácil de achar qual é o erro que causa o problema específico que você mencionou.

Comment: Ok, colocarei o código na íntegra assim q chegar no trabalho.

Comment: Eu não usaria sessão se fosse você, ou então limparia todas as sessões ao logar com um usuário novo. O grande problema com elas é justamente esse, de vez em quando o PHP se confunde com alguns sesids e acaba acessando uma sessão que não é a que você quer, ainda mais se o sistema estiver em rede e se os usuários estão acessando da mesma máquina.

Comment: @KhaosDoctor, no início da página login.php eu tenho isso:
    unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
Exatamente pra limpar a sessao.

Comment: Não há possibilidade de outras sessões interferirem?

Comment: session_name('radocs');
session_set_cookie_params('420');
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();

Estou fazendo assim agora, o erro nao voltou a aparecer, foi uma única vez.

Comment: Nunca vi isso acontecer com PHP, tem certeza que está efetuando toda vez uma nova instancia do Statement do banco e setando os dados de autenticação? creio eu que de alguma forma o PHP está fazendo o "select" com dados antigos, veja se tem algo parecido

Comment: Eu não entendi por que foi feito a validação da senha fora da query e por que você não usou ` LIMIT 1`. Concordo com o @deFreitas deve ser algo nos dados retornados pela query